# OpenFileDialog C# show custom text

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0, visual-c++

Hi I am working on an Application using .net 4.5. What i need now is in an OpenFileDialog i need to show some custom text or hint message to the user.

In C++ structure there is something called `"lpTemplateName "` on setting this to whatever text that text will be displayed in File dialog.

How can we do this in C#? any pointers is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about the file dialog window title?

Comment: Perhaps a couple pictures with the default dialog resource and your custom one (using the C++ code you know about) would help us to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link to know how to do: [Click Me](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/openfiledialog-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: If your link dies, this answer becomes useless. Please post the relevant portions of the link here. I also don't see how it answers the question. I'm not what exactly the OP wants the dialog to look like, but I assume it's something that isn't a simple property of `OpenFileDialog`. The link just explains some of those simple properties.